# height and align-content: center is not working in css flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

"*height:100%*" and "*align-content: center*" are not working in css flexbox.

For below code, can someone please suggest how to align child element vertically?

```css
body {
    background-color: #eee;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(8, 8, 119);
}

.child {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child">
        SkillsEnabled
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching for alignments on the vertical scale, I suggest to work with flexbox `column` logic like so:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}

.child {
  background-color: chartreuse;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="child">
        <a href="#">SkillsEnabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```